# sequencial movieclip name in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm pretty unexperienced with Action Script but searched the forums extensively to try and find a solution to this simple problem.

I'm creating several copies of a MovieClip but I need them to have different names.

```
// this array gets several cities
var cities:Array = new Array(
{ nome:"london", pos_x:20, pos_y:10 },
{ nome:"nyc", pos_x:210, pos_y:210 }
);

// now i would loop the cities array and create a copy of city_img for each
var k:*;
for each (k in cities) {
    var mov:city_img = new city_img(); // city_img is a movieclip
    addChild(mov);
    mov.x = k.pos_x;
    mov.y = k.pos_y;
    mov.id = i;
    i++;
}
```

This code works but, as expected, `mov` gets **id=1**. Even though two movieclips are drawn on stage.

Can anyone help me on **assign different names** for each movieclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [name](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name) property no ?

```
// this array gets several cities
var cities:Array = new Array(
{ nome:"london", pos_x:20, pos_y:10 },
{ nome:"nyc", pos_x:210, pos_y:210 }
);

// now i would loop the cities array and create a copy of city_img for each
var k:*;
var i:int=0;
for each (k in cities) {
    var mov:city_img = new city_img(); // city_img is a movieclip
    addChild(mov);
    mov.x = k.pos_x;
    mov.y = k.pos_y;
    mov.id = i;
    mov.name=k.nome; // <-- here set the name of the movie clip
    i++;
}
```

Comment: getChildByName("london").play();